# iPhone 4S/6 fixing resolution by scale?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, screen-resolution

We know that iPhone 4/4S and iPhone 6 have the same @2x field inside the `image.xcassets`. But, due to the different screen size, is not possible for me to create a single image that fits both the devices.

For instance: A logo image with resolution 600 x 300 will work fine within iPhone 6 but will result too much bigger for iPhone 4/4S.

I know that maybe is not the best way to achieve that but my question was: instead of create a -480h version of every single image and overload the project, what if I handle the size different programmatically?

This is what I mean:

```
...

#define kSCALE_FACTOR 0,83

...

if(iPhone_4) {
    image2xForiPhone6.xScale = kSCALE_FACTOR;
    image2xForiPhone6.yScale = kSCALE_FACTOR;
}
```

This was just an idea. What do you think about that?

Edit: In case this question will result useless or stupid, can you give me any advice for handle my images catalog? :(

Comment: The simplest approach is to simply constrain the UIImageView, set the mode to 'scale to fill' and let iOS scale the image as required.

Comment: if possible, just split your logo image in different images (one for the background gradiant/color and one for the text and another for the logo itself maybe?) and then just apply auto-layout on those components so that it looks the way you want on all screen resolutions

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually I'm using SpriteKit and not Storyboards. Did it works anyways?

Comment: It will be similar, except not using constraints - you will need to set the frame of whatever item is holding your image (SKSpriteNode, SKScene etc) and then set the scale mode